# Which production house has produced the most number of hit movies (average rating > 8)?

Tags: mysql, sql

[![ERD][1]][1]

```
SELECT m.production_company, COUNT(r.movie_id) as movie_count,
RANK() OVER(
    ORDER BY 
    COUNT(r.movie_id) DESC
    ) prod_company_rank
FROM movie as m
INNER JOIN ratings as r
ON m.id = r.movie_id
WHERE r.avg_rating > 8
GROUP BY production_company;
```

[![Output][2]][2]

The result has correct production company but I don't understand why is NULL there, it had to be Dream Warrior and National Theatre Live
Please help me where am doing wrong
Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtnuN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rs8T.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is there because it is in your data.  You can see these rows using:

```
select m.*
from movies m
where m.production_company is null;
```

If you don't want them, then filter them out using:

```
where m.production_company is not null
```

in your query.

Answer (score -1):

**use this in where clause**

WHERE
avg_rating >8
AND production_company IS NOT NULL

Comment: Using `IS NOT NULL` is already suggested in the other answer.  When answering old questions please ensure that your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.